# Why can't arrays be resized?

Tags: java, arrays

What is the reason why arrays, primitive or otherwise, cannot be re-sized dynamically?

I know you can use `ArrayList`, but the implementation behind it is still an array of initial size (I think it's 50 by default), and when it exceeds 50, a new array will be created to contain those elements.

So, I am trying to understand the system specification of an array that make it unresizable.

Comment: Vague. No language specified.

Comment: I don't think is language specified.. because this applies to c++ and java.

Comment: This guy has a genuine question and I see people downvoting with no specific explaination.

Comment: i dont see any reason to downvote the question guys..

Comment: Default size of the array is 10. See [`new ArrayList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList()).

Answer (score 8):

This is a valid question, and the answer has to do with how computers actually work.

When you create an array, using `int[] array = new int[5]` for instance, the computer reserves five consecutive spaces in memory for the data to be contained in that array.  However, the spaces in memory after that can be used right away to store other information.  If the array were to be resized later on, that other information would have to be moved somewhere else in order for the array to get bigger.  That's a lot of shuffling that we don't want to deal with, so computer architects disallow array resizing to make things simpler.

Comment: yes.. and in case of dynamically created arrayLists (Arraylist, Vector etc). The old array is removed and a new array is created after copying the values from the old array. The new array need no necessarily be in the same place/memory location as the old one.

Answer (score 5):

An array is, under the hood, a contiguous block of memory.  Depending on what you initialize it to, it can be comparatively small, or comparatively large.

Let's say, for instance, I have an array of ten elements.

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

The underlying implementation of the JVM now has to ask the OS for 40 contigous bytes to be allocated to the program.  The OS obliges, and now you have 40 bytes which you can use by the familiar name `arr`.

Note that this array is likely sharing space on either side of it - there are other references or bits of information nearby it, and it can't just walk over to the eleventh position of itself and "claim" it.

Let's say we decide that 10 is too short.  We need to make it larger - by a factor of ten.

```
int arr2 = new int[100];
```

Now the OS has to find 400 bytes of space that's next to each other in memory, which may or may not be trivial given the lifecycle of objects, the runtime of garbage collection, and so forth.

Resizing arrays isn't simply moving references over a few memory places - it's about **finding new blocks of contiguous memory** to store the data.

---

You mention `ArrayList` - its curious in that it's backed by an array which does the resizing "automatically".  Well, there's a catch to that resizing operation - **it's expensive.**

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

That `ensureCapacityInternal` does some interesting things...eventually calling `ensureExplicitCapacity`...which eventually calls `grow`:

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

Essentially, every time it needs to resize, it allocates space equal to 1.5 times the original backing array.  This gets **expensive** very quickly if the `ArrayList` is considerably large - the system has to go out and find more and more contiguous memory to allocate, meaning the JVM has to find some more space that's contiguous, meaning more time spent garbage collecting, and ultimately meaning less performance.

And the above doesn't even *cover* copying the data back over.

Comment: "the above doesn't even cover copying the data back over." - For java, we only keep the "reference" which is cheaper in that sense. You are spot on how arraylist works, there is an alternative call linkedlist but each reference cost 2 more.. so is a give and take.. the best is to declare the arraylist with the initial size you require so that it doesn't rebuild itself.

Comment: In some object-oriented environments, every object reference is an index into a table which holds the object's real address.  In such environments, allowing the size of an object to change wouldn't be a problem if one could be certain nobody was using the object at the time.  The problem is that for such systems to be safe in a multi-threaded environment it's necessary to lock all accesses to an object, whereas arrays otherwise offer certain thread-safety guarantees even without locking.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you define an array of 16 bytes, an integer & another integer.

Now you wish to resize it...

```
======================================================
|| || || || || || || || || || || || || || || || || ||   --->  (Memory)
======================================================
\________________/\____/\____/  
 ----------------  ----  ----
      Array(16)     Int  Int
```

Does the array above seem easy to resize?

A new Array has to be allocated to next free memory chunk available, since the program has already reserved the blocks immediately after for the integers.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem **vectors** are there.

You should use vectors is like dynamically allocating memory.