# Why is an array's length immutable?

Tags: java, arrays

Why is an array's length immutable (at least in java)? I know next to nothing about the inner workings of a programming language, so to me it seems easy to make an array's length changeable. I assume that there is a good reason for array lengths being immutable, probably related to performance. Does anybody know this reason?

Sorry if this question has been asked before. If it has, I didn't find it in about 10 minutes of searching.

EDIT: I know that when an array is is initialized, a certain amount of memory is allocated. Why can't more memory be allocated?

Comment: More memory can't be allocated because arrays use sequential locations in memory for the elements, and the next location in memory may not be free

Comment: Check this question. I think it has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19782314/891194

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The essence of this problem lies in how language designers chose to partition up the tasks that a language needs to perform, and assign those to different constructs.

In Java, the standard array type has a fixed length, because it's intended to be a low-level, bare-bones implementation, that the developer can build on top of.

In contrast, if you want a more fully featured array, check out the `ArrayList<>` class. The idea is to give you, the developer, a wide range of choices for your tools, so you can always pick something appropriate for the job.

When talking about arrays, the machinery necessary to allow for variable-length arrays is nontrivial. So the creators of Java chose to put this functionality in the `ArrayList<>` class, rather than making it mandatory overhead for anyone who just wants a simple array.

Why is lengthening an array nontrivial? Computer memory is finite, so we have to store objects next to each other. When you want to lengthen your array, what if there's already another object in the nearby memory addresses?

In this case, there isn't enough space to lengthen the array in-place, so one has to move data around to make room. Usually this is done by finding an larger, empty block of memory, and copying the array over while lengthening it. The mathematics of how to do this in the best way possible (e.g. how much empty space to leave?) are interesting and nontrivial. `ArrayList<>` abstracts this process for you, so you don't have to handle it yourself, and you can be confident that the designers of the `ArrayList<>` class chose an implementation that will perform well (on average) for your application.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing to do with performance.  The length is the size which was allocated.  You can't change what you have already set when you created it.  The size is the amount of space actually allocated and you can't change this either.

What you can do is take a copy of the array with a different size.

Comment: I disagree with the "nothing to do with performance". A compact array is often the fastest way to implement a mapping from small integers to values.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how does that relate to the length being fixed?

Comment: IF you vary the length, you either need to reallocate -and that requires an extra indirection- or you need to use more complex -so more slower- data structures (e.g. a linked list or hash table of chunks). In C parlance, flexible or fixed array members are the fastest possible way to have arrays inside some `struct`...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch IMHO If you reallocate its not the same array any more, certainly not for Java.  You could construct something like a ByteBuffer which resizes like IOBuffer does, but you are really taking about a different data structure.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It's worse than that if one wants the kind of thread safety which arrays inherently provide.  One could design a thread-safe resizable array which required locking only for the resize operation (reads and writes of any elements which would exist before and after resizing could proceed while the array was being resized) but unless one imposes rather coarse granularity restrictions on array size one would have to use *triple* indirection, and one of the indirection levels would be very cache-unfriendly.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [Oracle's Java Array tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

The length is fixed because of the structure itself. When you define one, you specify a certain amount of elements for which an amount of memory must be allocated.

If you ever have to "resize" an array, you must create an array with a bigger capacity and copy the existing elements to it. There are plenty of ways to do this.

---

#### Edit

When creating an array, a certain amount of memory is allocated that is enough to store the amount of required instances (values for primitives, references for objects). Resizing an array implies extending that block of memory and there's no guarantee on it being contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

An array in almost any language has a fixed size.  It has to do with memory allocation:  when you tell Java that you want an array of size N, it goes out and allocates a contiguous block of memory.  The size is determined by N * (size of individual element).  The reason that the size can't be changed is because there's no guarantee of what's before or after the array in memory.  To add another element, you would need to "claim" the space in memory directly after your array.  However, this might already be used by something else.  To avoid the complications and overhead, they just made it so that you can't resize an array.

What you can do is allocate a new array of a larger size and copy all of the old elements into it.  This is how data structures like ArrayList work under the hood.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

An array type may be implemented so as to provide any two of the following:

- The ability to resize the array, and have references to the old array become references to the new one
- The ability for multiple threads to manipulate an array simultaneously and independently, without locking or other such measures, provided only that no two threads try to write the same part of the array, and that any thread which reads part of the array which was written in another thread will work correctly with either old or new data.
- Array element access using single- rather than double-indirection or triple-indirection.

While array types could have been constructed so as to allow references to an array of a given size to become references to an array of a different size, arrays would lose much of their thread safety.  To be sure, problems would only occur if array data was written while an array was being resized, but there's no nice way to guard against that possibility without using locks to guard all writes to the array, substantially increasing their cost.

As an alternative, one could have an array wrapper hold a reference to an arrays of references to elements, instead of holding elements directly, in which case an array could be expanded by taking a lock, copying all element references from the old array to a bigger one, allocating new objects to hold the new elements and putting references to them in the new array, updating the array reference so it points to the new array, and releasing a lock.  The lock would only be necessary to guard against simultaneous resize attempts.  Element reads and writes could proceed just fine without locking, since every element which exists in both old and new arrays would be guaranteed to be the same in both [i.e. both would hold references to the same object, and array writes wouldn't change the references stored in either array, but would instead modify the object identified by those references].  This approach could avoid the need for any sort of locking when doing anything other than resizing the array, but unfortunately would require an excessive amount of work when accessing any array element.

In designing the array types of .NET and Java, the implementers decided that the first trait above was the least important, and thus focused on providing the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Some programming languages DO actually allow this, such as VB.net's redim function.  With Java, C/C++, etc. it can be accounted for with other data structures, such as vectors and linked lists.

To add to this, when elements are stored in an array, they are stored contiguously (one after the other) so to resize it, what's done behind the scenes for languages that support it out of the box, is that a new array is actually created of the new size, and the contents are dumped into it (in VB.net's case, you have to explicitly tell it to copy the original contents as well, iirc).  The real problem with having arrays resizable on the fly is you'd need to know ahead of time how large the array could possibly get, so the proper amount of contiguous memory could be allocated to store all of the elements.

Comment: The VB.NET `Redim Preserve` statement takes a variable which holds a reference to an array and stores a reference to a new array in that variable.  Any variables which hold references to the original array will continue to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's a design choice. It's less about the way Java works on the inside and more about giving the programmer more freedom to use only the resources that they need.

A variable length collection, like an `ArrayList` comes with several methods, pointers and overheads. If your data isn't going to change size any time soon, why do you want that overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Java supports both arrays with immutable length, and `ArrayList` objects whose size can change.  As others have pointed out, the latter involves extra overhead; if a certain size is allocated for an array, and you later want to make it bigger, then in general either the code has to allocate new space for the bigger array and move the whole thing, or the `ArrayList` has to be implemented with links which can make it slower to traverse, or perhaps some combination of the two.  So it's a trade-off, and you can pick the one which best suits your needs.  The languages that I know of that only provide the second kind of array (Perl, JavaScript, PHP) are all interpreted languages, I think, which means that running programs in those language is going to be inherently slower, anyway; that may be the reason the designers of those languages figured performance wasn't quite as important.