# Array vs. ArrayList when position is important

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm a Java newbie with a quick Array vs. ArrayList question. I have an array of objects that can grow or reduce in size, but it's very important for me to maintain the position they were in relative to each other in the array. I'm thinking because of this I need to use Array instead of an ArrayList which can condense/shift elements around if they are removed/added.

The practical example: In my first Java application that I'm slugging through to learn the nuances of this language I'm making a basic poker game simulator. I have Player objects in an array representing the seats they are sitting at, and it's important to know where the dealer button (index) was placed before rotating it. Players being removed or added from an ArrayList will change the indices of the players, and that can throw off the next Player to get it. Dealer button movement is very player-placement specific.

Long story short - is using an Array the best way of handling elements in an array-type structure that need to maintain their position in the array? Is there a better method or logic to accomplish this? I apologize for the simple question but I couldn't find any other alternatives and wanted to confirm that this is the best route to take.

EDIT:

To further clarify, let me give an example of why ArrayList's element movement won't work:
Take three players and their indices in the array:

0 : Player One (Dealer button)
1: Player Two
2: Player Three

If player two (index one) gets up from the table before the dealer button is rotated, depending on the rules player one will *keep* the button and the blinds will be adjusted accordingly (there's other variants of this rule, but the one I like to use). In an ArrayList, the internal array will be condensed and player three will end up getting the button an extra round before he should. I need to track the empty seat that was active during the hand but was emptied before the round was over and the button moved.

I'm starting to realize that the concept of a "seat" is going to be more complicated, I need to track state on it, including "player just sat down while hand in progress," "player got up while hand in progress," etc.  @Stephen P - I think you're right about this, I'm going to need to track them separately and cannot use a simple array structure to determine the logic. Timing of when the elements are added and/or removed is paramount to the application logic, and simply examining if an element is there or not won't cut it.

For the Seats themselves, I'm learning towards ArrayList since the Seats will now *always* be there, no empties. The Seat will just have a reference to the Player object if one is sitting there as well as WHEN that player arrived. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What makes you think `ArrayList` doesn't maintain element order?

Comment: I know it does maintain the order, but I need to know the exact placement, including empty seats between players. It's the tracking of the empty (null) players between each other that is also important.

Comment: `arrayList.add(index, element)` is the same as doing `array[index] = element`. Just use an ArrayList.

Comment: @RedAlert not exactly, first of all the arraylist has to have at least <index> number of elements, secondly add() shifts the elements from <index> one place "higher"

Comment: @RedAlert: You had *almost* the same idea as me, but you're wrong: `add` shifts the subsequent elements, assignment does not. But you can do simple assignments with both `ArrayList` and `Array`.

Comment: `arrayList.add(index, element)` is *not* the same as doing `array[index] = element`.  It inserts the new element at the index and moves everything from index forward up by one.

Comment: There are a fixed number of *seats* at the table; a player leaving does not remove the seat, so I would model the seats separately from the players.

Comment: It kind of sounds like what you really want is a `Map<Integer, Player>`.

Comment: @StephenP Thank you sir, that's the exact piece of advice that got my brain moving in a different (and better) direction. I think this was more of a high-level logic issue rather than a data storage issue (see edit in post). Thank you!

Comment: @Chris I would go one step further than that and use `NavigableMap<Integer, Player>` which maintains order and has easy ways of traversing keys in the map. Which makes sense since Java's implementation is a `TreeMap`.

Comment: I think it's extremely important to understand that an ArrayList is just one of the many tools in the JDK Collections. Like any tool it works great for some things (like a stack implementation) but poor for others (such as a FIFO queue). It's all about matching the right tool to the job. The advantage of the JDK Collections data structures over the simple array are all of the additional methods that come with in addition to compatibility with generics. For additional information check out this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Answer (score 2):

With ArrayList, you can make your players sit tight by using set(int index, T value). You just have to fill the arrayList with nulls first:

```
List<Player> seats = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(numPlayers,(Player)null));
seats.set(2,player); // Place a player in the third chair
seats.set(1,null); // Empty the second chair
```

Answer (score 1):

> Long story short - is using an Array the best way of handling elements
>   in an array-type structure that need to maintain their position in the
>   array? Is there a better method or logic to accomplish this? I
>   apologize for the simple question but I couldn't find any other
>   alternatives and wanted to confirm that this is the best route to
>   take.

Position shouldn't be your most important criterion for choosing array vs. ArrayList, at least I don't believe it should be.

Arrays are covariant, and more performant most of the time.  They mix poorly (if at all) with Java generics which is really kind of a big deal a lot of the time.  You cannot create a reference to a new instance of an array of a non-reifiable type (though you can receive one, but buyer beware).

ArrayLists, as a part of the Java Collections API, are invariant.  For this reason they work much better with Java generics and, according to Joshua Bloch (Essential Java, 2nd Ed), should be favored much of the time.  ArrayLists should often be less performant (and less concise) than arrays.  Moreover, as part of the Java Collections API, ArrayLists are more flexible because they extend the List interface which enables you to change implementations from ArrayList to any other List provided that your own class that implements the List is well encapsulated (i.e. the ArrayList is not part of your class's exported API).

There are other differences, of course, but these are the ones that really stand out.  If you were really concerned about performance, you could create your own List implementation that was backed by arrays (like ArrayList is) in order to get a feature or the API contract you really wanted.  Otherwise, to me, it sounds like you should be using ArrayList (or even other Collection type such as Map (suggested)).

Comment: I'd like to see "more performant" or "less performance" in context. An ArrayList is just a smart wrapper for an array - not sure why/how another implementation would be faster - and after the JIT has a say the effective performance should be very darn close.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant number of seats, you can use either an array or an `ArrayAist`. If you want to increase the number of seats, you will need an `Arraylist`, because regular arrays are immutable. See this for more information on the immutability of arrays: [Why is an array's length immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007600/why-is-an-arrays-length-immutable/20007668#20007668) An `ArrayList` will never move around its contents if you only use the `get(int index)` and `set(int index, E element)`

Also, it is bad practice to let `null` mean something, even if that something is nothing.

The code:

**seat ArrayList initialization**

```
List<Person> seats = new ArrayList<Person>(max_Number_Of_Seats_here);
for(Person person : seats)
{
    person = new Person("");
}
//You can then set people like this:
seats.set(seat_index_here, new Person("Darkprozac"));
```

And have the parameter for the constructor for the class `Person` be its name.

**Person constructor**

```
...
public String name;
public Person(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
...
```

You can then check if the `Person`'s `name` is `""`, and if it is, skip that person:

**Check if seat is empty**

```
...
for(Person person : seats)
{
    if(person.name.equals(""))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
...
```

You can also wrap a `Person` in a `Seat` class:

**Seat Class**

```
public class Seat
{
    public Person person;
    public String state;
    public Seat(String name)
    {
        if(name.equals("");
        {
            state = "empty";
        }
        else
        {
            state = "full";
            person = new Person(name);
        }
    }
}
```

and then modify **seat ArrayList initialization** and **Check if seat is empty** accordingly.

*Thanks to MrBackend for pointing out that I was wrong about `ArrayLists` initializing as null.*

Comment: Remember to fill the list with nulls first! Otherwise there will be an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Arrays are never immutable.  Arrays are always mutable.  The *component type* of an array may be immutable (but doesn't have to be), but arrays are always mutable.  It is wrong to say "...because arrays are immutable".  I think your point is that the length fixed, but this is very different from immutability as this term is commonly understood.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map, specifically, a `TreeMap`.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Player> seats = new TreeMap<Integer, Player>();
Integer first = seats.firstKey();
Integer next = seats.nextKey(first);
```

This gives the benefits of a map, you don't have to worry about seats shifting (even accidentally), and you can still navigate seats easily.

The map manages its own storage (unlike an array) and does not have a risk of shifting indices (unlike an `ArrayList`).